# scrollspy no me funciona bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, css3

hola tengo el siguiente menú de Bootstrap 4 y quiero que al hacer scroll se cambie el color de las opciones del menú. pero no me funciona nada de lo que pruebo. en Bootstrap 3 me funcionaba pero ahora con el 4 nada de lo que pruebo me funciona ni javascript ni poniendo data-offset="50" en el body.

```css
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-custom-1  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">

            <img class="navbar-brand logo" src="assets/img/logo-f.png" alt="">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav" aria-controls="main-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav">
                <!-- navbarSupportedContent -->

                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li><a  href="#about1">Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="#curses1">Cursos</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="#services">Servicios</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="#partner">Partner</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="#contact">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

<article class="study">
                <h1 id="about1" class="prueba">¿klklklklklklklk</h1>
                <p>klklklklk.</p>
                <p>lklklklklklklklklklklklklkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                            <p>klklklklklk</span></p>
                            <p><span class="text-target">klklklklklk</span></p>
                            <p>lorem.</p>
                      </div>
                        <div class="col-sm col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                             <img src="assets/img/img2.jpg" class="img-study center-block" alt="">
                                </div>
                        </div>

             </article>
```

también he usado estos scripts

```
    $('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
      var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
    });


    $('body').scrollspy({ target: '.navbar', offset:50 });

    function update_scroll_spy()
        {
            $('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function ()
            {
                var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
            });
        }
```

y este css para el cambio de color.

```
.navbar-custom-1 .navbar-nav > li > .active > a,
 .navbar-custom-1 .navbar-nav > li > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-custom-1 .navbar-nav > li > .active > a:focus {
   color: red;
 }
```

Comment: Debes tener un ID, tanto en los elementos del menú como en el contenido al que se hará scroll. No veo que lo implementes en tu código.

Comment: no he puesto el resto del codigo pero tengo en cada seccion un h1 con un id equivalente con los del menu. pero no consigo hacer que me funcione